# Button inside Div isn't showing with the div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button inside a . The div has an id = "winningMsg". Button has no id.

But only the div text is showing and the button remains hidden.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
document.getElementById("winningMsg").style.display = "block";
```

```html
<div id="winningMsg">
  <button type="button" onclick="restart()">Restart</button>
</div>
```

Comment: try `<div id="winningMsg">`

Comment: When we fix your typo, the code works as you can see - voting to close as `typo` type question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to put double quotes to id tag:

```html
<div id="winningMsg">
     <button type = "button" onclick="restart()">Restart</button>
</div>
```